# Formulate POST request in curl

Tags: c#, rest, post, curl

I'm using curl to send POST request to web service http ://localhost 2325//Service

How can I desirialize body of the POST request into a variable which I could then access within my POST method ?

Can someone give me an example?

This is my method

```
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/user", Method = "POST")] public void Create(User us)
```

Class User contains `user_id` and `user_name.`

Can anyone please help?
All I need is an example how to formulate POST request in curl

I've tried this but it doesn't work

curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d ' `{"user":{"user_name":"Name1","user:id":"11"}}'`  http:// localhost :3000/api/1/users

Comment: It's not clear how this question relates to `curl`. Could you expand further?

Comment: are you sending it in json format that you want to  desirialize

Comment: Yes I am, I'm sending json format. I already have a class User (from database)

Comment: Why are you using curl with C#? You realize that there are several methods build into .NET to fill this need, correct?

Comment: Because curl is a great way to manually test these sorts of services without resorting to writing C# client classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you named your parameter `us` in the method signature your JSON needs to be:

```
{"us":{"user_name":"Name1","user:id":"11"}}
```

Alternatively rename your parameter "user" in the method signature.

Comment: I get error in curl : (globbing) nested braces not supported at pos(8)

Comment: there is a space at `-d ' {` (before the brace), try removing that (just in case)

Comment: and the UriTemplate and URL you are trying to reach look suspect to me; do you have some special routing rule for this case?

Comment: so shouldn't you instead be posting to `localhost:2342/MyService/users` instead of :3000 with a Rails-esque route?